# What I need to save in data base in order to be able convert to UTC?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

My problem is: I have a lot of data containg a date time (in own local time) and I need to convert It to UTC. It looks so:

```
class Data
{
  int id; //Some id for database
  DateTime time; //Time in local time, i need to convert it to utc
}

//Converting:
1)Find this id in database and extract some info (which excatly?)
2)Convert time to UTC
```

My question is: which sort of data I need to keep in database in order to convert time correctly?

My version is: to keep an integer difference in hours between local time and utc and convert by adding It to local time. But Is this appropriate solution?

Comment: Will your application actually run across multiple time zones?

Answer (score 1):

The generally accepted solution is to always store the UTC date time and then convert it into local time when loading or displaying it to the user

Answer (score 0):

Keeping an integer difference is not enough, because this doesn't differentiate between say daylight saving time (DST) and non-DST.

The best way is to keep a time zone. Universal and very well supported time zone system is [Olson Tz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

They are references by names of big cities, which are representative of the time zone. For example Pasific Time would be America\Los_Angeles. Note that this includes both daylight and non-daylight based on what the stored date is. So you don't need to know when daylight caomes into play - this is incorporated in the olson time zone.

Look [here](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm) too.